# Name of the textarea appears at bottom

Tags: css, textarea

I have a textarea named(not the attribute of textarea;but its name ) Summery . But the name appears at bottom ,and I want it to display in the mid or top . HOw can I achieve this ?

`<div class="edit_i">Pitch Summery :<textarea>{$k->pitch_summery}</textarea></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the "Pitch Summery" text?

make sure that the div has vertical-align:top; css property

```
.edit_i textarea{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TrdbC/1/

Comment: Thanks Emil.But it works only in chrome . I have Firefox 5.0 and Safari 4.0.3,its not working there ! Why ?

Comment: Try http://jsfiddle.net/TrdbC/1/. I added textarea, which seems more cross-browser

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick example.

```
<style>
.label {
   display: block;
}

</style>

<label for='textarea' class='label'>Pitch Summery</label>
<textarea value="{$k->pitch_summery}" id='textarea'></textarea>
```